# Профилировщик Visual Studio 2017: Failed to analyze report, Отказано в доступе по пути C:\Program files\dotnet\мой_проект.dll

Tags: c#, .net-core, профилирование

Попытался сделать профилирование и оно упало с ошибкой, как описано в вопросе. Я понять не могу, зачем он лезет по этому пути: `C:\Program files\dotnet\название_моего_проекта.dll`. Проект расположен совсем в другом месте, в папке `dotnet` даже файла нет того, который он там ищет.

Сами файлы отчётов создаются, однако при попытке открытия возникает ошибка `В файле нет буферов данных`.

Также привожу полный текст вывода профилировщика:

> Предупреждение VSP2347: Данные счетчика производительности "Монитору
>   не удалось установить драйвер производительности VS.  Отказано в
>   доступе. Попробуйте использовать параметр /Admin:Driver,Install
>   команды VSPerfCmd из окружения с повышенными правами." и обнаружение
>   выполнения режима ядра отключены.
>
> Профилирование начато.
>
> Встроенное инструментирование
>   C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\название_моего_проектаProtocol\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\название_моего_проекта.dll
>   Сообщение VSP3049: малозначимые функции будут исключены из
>   инструментирования.
>
> Послекомпоновочное инструментирование Microsoft (R) VSInstr15.0.27102
>   x64
>
> (C) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.). Все права защищены.
>
> Предупреждение VSP2006: Не удалось обнаружить PDB для 
>   C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\название_моего_проекта\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\название_моего_проекта.dll
>   Файлы для обработки:
>   C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\название_моего_проекта\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\название_моего_проекта.dll
>   --> C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\название_моего_проекта\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\название_моего_проекта.dll
>
> Резервная копия исходного файла сохранена в
>   C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\название_моего_проекта\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\название_моего_проекта.dll.orig
>
> Успешно инструментирован файл
>   C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\название_моего_проекта\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\название_моего_проекта.dll.
>
> Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\название_моего_проекта.dll".
>
> Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\название_моего_проекта.instr.pdb".
>
> Данные записаны в
>   C:\Users\имя_пользователя\source\repos\название_моего_проекта\dotnet190812(2).vsp.
>
> Профилирование завершено.
>
> Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\название_моего_проекта.dll".
>
> Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\название_моего_проекта.instr.pdb".
>
> Профилирование завершено.

Профилировщиками ранее не пользовался. Могу не знать элементарного, просьба больно не бить :)

Comment: А есть код ошибки какой-нибудь?

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Сейчас, к сожалению, не могу посмотреть. Завтра сообщу.

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Посмотрел. Никакого кода ошибки Visual studio не пишет, только текст.

Comment: Мне кажется [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705465/build-net-core-as-an-exe-not-a-dll) ответ может вам помочь. Я могу перевести его, если нужно

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus Вы считаете, что сборка приложения в `.exe` вместо `.dll` поможет решить проблему? Я посмотрел, у меня нет `.json`-файла, приведённого в том ответе. Вообще нет `.json` в решении.

Comment: Возможно, так как я [натыкался](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/725) на сообщение (хоть и трехлетней давности), где, как я понимаю, разработчик говорит о проблемах профилирования .net core приложений. *Хотя последний коммент говорит о том, что в VS 2017 с этим не должно быть проблем*

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97336/discussion-between-v-mor-and-nonforgivingjesus).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующие шаги (в порядке следования, если не получается):

1) запустите студию с правами администратора (прямо в свойствах запуска укажите)

2) поставьте все обновления для VS и ОС, перезапустите машину и повторите п.1 (если у Вас есть SSDT для MS SQL, то его тоже следует обновить до версии совместимой с VS 2017)

3) пересоздайте свое решение на другом одном диске, создавая новые проекты и файлы, скопировав содержимое из текущего решения (самое трудоемкое)

Comment: Я с самого начала догадывался, что права администратора решат проблему. Однако у меня их нет и получить никак не получится.

Comment: Тогда попросите системного админа настроить запуск VS с правами админа в свойствах приложения

Comment: То есть без прав админа не получится никак?

Comment: Судя по описанию проблемы нет, нужны админские права

Comment: А можете дать в ответе подробное объяснение, зачем он обращается по этому пути и в чём вообще суть ошибки?

Comment: Увы не могу, т к сначала нужно попробовать по тому алгоритму, что я описал выше, а потом уже делать выводы.
Возможно не поможет.
Однако, VS без админских прав у меня по опыту глючил на разных задачах и в лог выдавал непонятные пути и что к ним нет доступа.
Потому и предположил, что нужны админские права